# elevateZoom - jQuery image zoom plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, plugins, opencart

I would like to know how to enable zoom on my website when displayed on mobile (especially in Chrome browser).

I am using elevate Zoom - a jQuery image zoom plugin - it is working on desktop but the mobile view does not work.

Plugin used : https://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples/#mousewheel

Site (Desktop is working): https://www.shadowboxmilitarygear.com/Vietnam-T-shirt-for-the-back

I need the plugin to working with mobile as well.

Do you have any ideas of what I can do to enable the zoom on mobile chrome?

Comment: I've had a quick look at the Shadowbox website and mobile is broken quite badly - I think mobile zoom is the least of your issues. Is this a custom theme, can you change these attributes? This CSS is making the layout break in mobile view `.productpage .product-left {
    padding-right: 24px;
    width: 50.5%;
}
.productpage .product-right {
    padding: 0 24px 0 0; 
    width: 49.5%; 
}`

Comment: sorry, @Daniel issue was solved. problems was if($(window).width() > 768) { 
i changes width. thanks for response to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<select id="select"> 
<option value="1">Front</option>
<option value="2">Back</option>
<option value="3">Scenery</option>
<option value="4">Side</option>
</select>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("#zoom_09").elevateZoom({
            gallery : "gallery_09",
            galleryActiveClass: "active"
                }); 


     $("#select").change(function(e){
   var currentValue = $("#select").val();
   if(currentValue == 1){    
   smallImage = 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image1.png';
   largeImage = 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image1.jpg';
   }
   if(currentValue == 2){    
   smallImage = 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image2.png';
   largeImage = 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image2.jpg';
   }
   if(currentValue == 3){    
   smallImage = 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image3.png';
   largeImage = 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image3.jpg';
   }
   if(currentValue == 4){    
   smallImage = 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/small/image4.png';
   largeImage = 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/zoom/images/large/image4.jpg';
   }
    // Example of using Active Gallery
  $('#gallery_09 a').removeClass('active').eq(currentValue-1).addClass('active');       


     var ez =   $('#zoom_09').data('elevateZoom');    

  ez.swaptheimage(smallImage, largeImage); 

    });
```

very helpful